# Cannot do temporary change in brightness

Tags: gnome, brightness

I mainly use my netbook for writing and browsing. So I have set the brightness to a minimum level. Sometimes when I watch videos I increase the brightness using hotkeys. But when increased after few seconds it reverts back to the default level I have set. Is there any way in which the brightness level I have set using hotkeys can be retained untill the machine is shutdown?

Comment: are you on battery power?

Comment: please add the model and manufacturer details, to check if its a problem that many others are facing.

Answer (score 1):

check the brightness section at the end on [launchpad.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AspireTimeline/Fixes) Its for a Acer Aspire. Googling tells that only some of Dells, Acers and Toshibas have that problem.